# pcm resample before porcupine (python)

Tags: python

After a little help if anyone would be able. I have a microphone that will only operate at 44100. Porcupine expects 16000. I'm trying to resample before porcupine but running into an error.
Snippet of code

```
def resample(pcm, input_rate, new_rate):
    data16 = np.frombuffer(buffer=pcm, dtype=np.int16)
    sample = signal.resample(data16, (int(len(data16) / input_rate * new_rate))
    sample16 = np.array(resample, dtype=np.int16)
    return sample16.tobytes()

pcm = audio_stream.read(porcupine.frame_length)
            input_rate = sample_rate
            new_rate = 16000
            new_pcm = resample(pcm, input_rate,new_rate)
            new_pcm = struct.unpack_from("h" * porcupine.frame_length,new_pcm)
            result = porcupine.process(new_pcm)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error

```
pcm = struct.unpack_from("h" * porcupine.frame_length,pcm)
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 1024 bytes for unpacking 1024 bytes at offset 0 (actual buffer size is 370)
```

Where am I being dumb. Help appreciated

Comment: Pad your buffer to the right size?